# trace opening on a certain file

Tags: lsof, strace

I know how to strace a certain program to see all the files it reads. I know how to see what processes are using a certain file at the moment.

But is there a way to log all file opens. I want something like `tail -f some/log/file` but instead `lsof -f /file/someone/might/open/soon` which prints out info every time something opens that file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an Auditing System. You didn't specify your OS, I assume Linux. Check http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd and the `See also` pages at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inotify to run lsof when the file is accessed.  For example, in the incrontab:

```
/etc/passwd IN_ACCESS /tmp/lsof.sh $@
```

Incrontab doesn't seem to use the shell, so redirects can't be used.  A wrapper can be used instead:

```
lsof -f -- $1 >> /tmp/lsof.log
```